# Chrome fails to launch after Windows update installs KB5004237

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-update

Uninstalling KB5004237 allows me to launch Google Chrome again. Yet automatic Windows Update causes re-installation of this "fix" and Chrome fails to launch again. Forcing me to use Edge. I've tried various troubleshooting suggestions and nothing works to get Chrome started. Attempt to run Chrome setup starts OK but then hangs up before completion.

Answer (score 1):

That KB in the question was from last week (Windows 10 Patch Tuesday) and does not affect Chrome here.

Make sure you have a backup of favorites , remove (uninstall) extensions, and completely uninstall Chrome.

Now restart your computer, check for any updates, install Chrome and test.

Comment: Did every step you suggested in order and same failure to open Chrome.

Comment: Try the following: Again uninstall Chrome and Extensions, open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth and then SFC /SCANNOW . Restart when done , install Chrome and test.  Failure at this point means a Repair Install for Windows 10.

Comment: Now uninstall Chrome fails to complete!

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with two of my clients this morning.

I manged to pull the data from Event Viewer but I never found any fix that worked for my two users.  Maybe the info will help someone else.  I ended up removing the aforementioned update.  It's worth noting that, just like my two clients, I have the latest version of Google Chrome installed along with this same update and mine is fine - for now.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          7/20/2021 10:08:55 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-25PKALC
Description:
Faulting application name: chrome.exe, version: 91.0.4472.164, time stamp: 0x60ef17ce
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1110, time stamp: 0x4809adf2
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000002a318
Faulting process id: 0xd100
Faulting application start time: 0x01d77d70c62cdc5e
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 749f9cd6-da81-4282-bd69-023aface2bd2
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-07-20T14:08:55.0733245Z" />
    <EventRecordID>15204</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-25PKALC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>chrome.exe</Data>
    <Data>91.0.4472.164</Data>
    <Data>60ef17ce</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.19041.1110</Data>
    <Data>4809adf2</Data>
    <Data>c0000409</Data>
    <Data>000000000002a318</Data>
    <Data>d100</Data>
    <Data>01d77d70c62cdc5e</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>749f9cd6-da81-4282-bd69-023aface2bd2</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**Update 2021-07-23:**
Over the last several days, I've worked with one of our customers who had this issue.  We tried multiple things but ended up doing a Windows *reset*.  We chose the option to keep apps and files in place so we don't loose everything.  It was fine after that but only until KB5004237 was installed again.  As soon as I can, I'll be jumping into his machine and ripping out the update.

Again, I never like removing updates because they tend to do more good than bad.  However, in this case, these people have processes that they do in their daily routines and taking away Chrome from them messes with their process and their morale.  (Being *stuck* in their job 8+ hours a day is bad enough and taking away their favorite browser sets them off pretty quickly.)  While I have the update installed and I run Chrome without issue, I'm a FF user for my personal stuff so I wouldn't be affected anyway.  So, yes, you can have them not use Chrome but, you may catch some flack from your paying customers when their IT staff tells them to use another browser.

Comment: "..ended up removing KB5004237". If I do that to fix problem again, how to live with Windows update wanting to "fix me"? What is your plan for that issue? Verified on another PC here that this problem exists only on my PC (Dell Inspiron 15 7000 runing Home edition.

Comment: Unfortunately, for now, our plan is to wait it out.  We're hoping that MS and/or Google will put out an update that will supersede their respective versions currently installed.  I'm telling my clients to avoid installing that update again if we've removed it.  It's not best practice nor is it our SOP but we need our paying customers to remain paying customers for the time being.

Comment: Exactly how do you "avoid installing that update" with Windows Update automatic behavior?

Comment: Leave Windows Update service in Disabled mode?

Comment: @JohnAdams, our clients have the ability to pause updates seven days, as we don't manage the service via Group Policy.  Others may have to change policies, if they use them.

Comment: There was an update to Google Chrome for Windows within the last 24 hours. That may be worth a look as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with KB5004237. It first affected me, but I didn't think much about it. Then the next day, another user had the issue. Two days later, a couple more users were affected. Traced it to KB5004237 being installed. Renaming the exe for Edge/Chrome fixes it until they auto update and its broke again. Don't want to roll back the update as its suppose to somewhat fix the print hack. Told users to use Firefox in the meantime until MS and/or Chrome addresses and fixes the problem.